# Validate presence of field only if another field is blank - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with a mobile/cell number and a home phone number.

I want to have only validate presence of mobile/cell number if the phone number has been left blank or vice versa.

My current validations for these fields are as follows.

```
validates_presence_of :mobile_number
validates_presence_of :home_phone

validates_length_of :home_phone, :minimum => 12, :maximum => 12
validates_length_of :mobile_number, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10, :allow_blank => true

validates_format_of :home_phone, :with => /\A[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}/, :message => "format should be 02 9999 9999"
```

I thought I could have something like the following but not sure how to do this exactly.

```
validates_presence_of :mobile_number, :unless => :home_phone.blank?
```

I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You don't need a lambda. This will do:

```
validates_presence_of :mobile_number, :unless => :home_phone?
```

Also, all of the validators take the same if/unless options, so you can make them conditional at will.

*Update:* Looking back at this answer a few days later, I see that I should explain why it works:

- If you set a validator's `:unless` option to be a symbol, Rails will look for an instance method of that name, invoke that method on the instance that's being validated -- at validation time -- and only perform the validation if the method returns false.
- ActiveRecord automatically creates question mark methods for each of your model's attributes, so the existence of a `home_phone` column in your model's table causes Rails to create a handy `#home_phone?` method. This method returns true if and only if home_phone is present (i.e. not blank). If the home_phone attribute is nil or an empty string or a bunch of white space, home_phone? will return false.

---

UPDATE: Confirmed that this old technique continues to work in Rails 5.

Comment: I edited this answer to be in line with my experience on Apache/Passenger with Rails 3. The app refused to even start with `:unless => :home_phone?`, and my theory is that the method lookup was happening too soon.

Comment: Don't make such large edits with unclear attribution. Explain your different experience in a comment or another answer. I've reverted some of your change and attributed the remainder.

Comment: I spent some time debugging and I'm just trying to help the next guy out. If you insist that the lambda isn't necessary, please explain how to get it working, or update your answer to include it.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help. I'm just saying: don't edit an answer that begins "You don't need a lambda" by sticking in a lambda. It's nonsensical, and it's not what I wrote. Another answer uses a lambda and you're welcome to vote it up and mine down or to offer contrary comments. This answer works for me, as is, so I'm not sure why it didn't work in your case.

Comment: Oops: I was trying to edit as little as possible, leaving in "you don't need a lambda" was a dumb mistake. Sorry. What version of Rails and what server did you have it working under?

Comment: I've tried it in 3.1.0 and 3.2.2. Is it possible you're trying to validate a model before the class has finished loading? I'm not sure why there'd be a reason to look up the method before validation.

Comment: What if home_phone is a boolean?

Comment: A problem with this method is that the check will be truthy for value of 0 integer.

Comment: saved me from having to write my own validation method :) in Rails 5

Answer (score 23):

You must use a `lambda` / `Proc` object:

```
validates_presence_of :mobile_number, :unless => lambda { self.home_phone.blank? }
```

Comment: I think you mean :if instead of :unless (or #present? instead of #blank?). Also, a lambda is not necessary.

Comment: @RyanBigg, yeah lambda does, but I was asking Paul why my symbol-based answer didn't work.

Comment: Because `home_phone` may return an empty string, which *I think* would make the validation pass anyway. The boolean method I think only checks for `nil`.

Comment: No, `home_phone?` (with a question mark) is false if the `home_phone` attribute is blank (nil or empty string). I wonder if Paul accidentally left off the question mark. That would be critical.

Comment: @RobDavis - I know it's old but just FYI as I haven't seen any corrections to this: on Rails 5 your approach doesn't work either. Lambda / Proc does.

Comment: @silverdr My answer works fine on Rails 5 for me. Perhaps you can share some of your failing code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @RobDavis - absolutely! I am also very interested. Here's the line that works: `validates_presence_of :string_value, unless: lambda {self.integer_value.present? || self.decimal_value.present?}` (can't put proper code in the comment). Here are the lines that don't: `validates_presence_of :string_value, unless: :integer_value? || :decimal_value?` and `validates_presence_of :string_value, unless: (:integer_value? || :decimal_value?)`

Comment: The `unless` parameter is expecting a symbol, like `:integer_value?` It doesn't take a boolean expression like that. For an expression that you want to be evaluated at validation time, you will need a lambda, but that's different  from the situation in the original post.

Answer (score 9):

Starting in Rails 4, you can pass a block to presence. Concisely:

```
validates :mobile_number, presence: {unless: :home_phone?}
```

Also, `:home_phone?` returns false for nil or blank.

Comment: This works, but I'd point out you're passing a hash of `unless: :home_phone?`, not a block of code (which would just be `{ !home_phone? }` )

Answer (score 6):

Tested in Rails 7, this works flawlessly:

```
validates :mobile_number, presence: { unless: :home_phone }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way that works in rails 4

```
  validates_presence_of :job, if: :executed_at?

  validates :code,
            presence: true,
            length:  { minimum: 10, maximum: 50 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
            numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

a short solution:

```
validates_presence_of :mobile_number, unless: -> { home_phone.blank? }
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Rails, instead of relying on old `validates_presence_of`, you should use `validates` and list validations for each attribute:

```
validates :mobile_number, presence: { if: -> { home_phone.present? } }
```