# Rails 3 Handle Ongoing Employment Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building an `employments` table which contains `start_date` and `end_date`

```
create_table :employments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id
      t.string :title
      t.string :department
      t.string :summary
      t.date :start_date
      t.date :end_date
      t.timestamps
end
```

It's good for creating past employments, but not for current employment since the user is still employed.

How to handle when user tries to indicate he/she is currently employed, so that the user doesn't have to select the `:end_date`. (I know LinkedIn offers a option that allows users to click on "I'm currently working here" to avoid choosing `:end_date`, but in database, how is this achieved?)

I use simple_form for `:employments` edit and new. The date fields are date selectors.

Comment: When you said "how to handle when user tries to indicate he/she is currently employed" are you having the user fill out some form? In any case, in terms of the database and those fields alone, a good indicator that a user is still employed is when `:end_date` is `nil`.

Comment: @mmichael so I just put out a checkbox in the form that overrides the input field for `:end_date` to nil?

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. Assuming that you don't currently have a validator for `:end_date` in your `Employment Model`, unless you pass a value for `:end_date` in your form the default is `nil`. So, back to your point, yes you can have a checkbox in your form that says "Currently employed?" and set the value to `nil` in your Controller action.

Comment: @mmichael Okay, I'm gonna give a shot, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, why not just set the `end_date` field to `nil` and treat that value as "currently employed" in your UI?

Answer (score 1):

What about a validates_presence_of with an :unless conditional?

Here's an example:

[Validate presence of field only if another field is blank - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273289/validate-presence-of-field-only-if-another-field-is-blank-rails)

Comment: Yea, seems like leaving it as `nil` is the way to go, so I guess I could offer a checkbox and some javascript to overrides the `:end_date` value to nil. But it's gonna be a bit ugly cuz the form_field divides the date into year, month, and day

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm gonna pick regulatethis's answer since that one is first. I will come back and vote yours up when I have enough rep.

Comment: No problem. There's several ways to do what you want and good info out there on how to implement them. It all depends on how you want it to work. Happy Railsing!