# Rails - Validates params depends on other params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have 2 fields which is `mobile_no` and `telephone_no`. I want to validate this fields with the following condition:

```
If mobile_no is present on submit, then
  don't validate telephone_no


if telephone_no is present on submit, then
  don't validate mobile_no
```

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273289/validate-presence-of-field-only-if-another-field-is-blank-rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this one in your model:

```
validates :mobile_no, presence: true, unless: :telephone_no?
validates :telephone_no, presence: true, unless: :mobile_no?
```