# Validate the presence of one of two fields when one might be zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I just came across a situation where the accepted solution for [Validate presence of field only if another field is blank - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6273289/7098196) wasn't complete.

I'd like one or both of two fields to be present but in my case one of the fields `points` needs to be a number between 0 and 10. In cases where the points field is zero `:points?` is evaluating to false and a blank comment is considered invalid. I tried to make it a little more specific by specifying `:points.blank?`:

```
validates :comment, presence: { unless: :points.blank?, on: :create }
validates :points, presence: { unless: :comment?, on: :create }, 
                   numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_nil: true, less_than_or_equal_to: 10, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
```

That seems to work (I can save the first entry with 0 points and no comment) but on subsequent saves I'm getting weird errors from the controller:

> NoMethodError (undefined method 'validate' for false:FalseClass):
>   app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in 'create'

Is there something else I need to do with the validation? Do I need to use a lambda (as suggested in some answers to the linked question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you got first record working, but this is not correct syntax:

> validates :comment, presence: { unless: :points.blank?, on: :create }

Instead you should be defining a method like this in your model:

```
def points_blank?
  # your code for zero handling
  # 
end
```

and then use that method in unless like this:

```
validates :comment, presence: { unless: :points_blank?, on: :create }
```

Comment: Ended up going with: `validate :has_comment_or_points, on: :create` and doing all the logic in that method

Answer (score 2):

`:points.blank?` evaluates to `false`, which is being set as the value of the `:unless` key in your hash. You will need to specify a method name or Proc for the `:unless` option to work. You can simplify the whole setup:

```
validates :comment, presence: true, on: :create, if: :points?
validates :points, numericality: :only_integer, inclusion: 0..10
```

Comment: Thanks @coreyward but that (using `unless: :points?` instead of `if: :points?`) takes me back to my original problem. If I give someone zero points I can't give them a blank comment. Validation fails because `:points?` evaluates to false when `:points => 0`.

Comment: @MatthewLindfieldSeager You can create your own method then. `def points_present?; points.present?; end`